# Openlayers 6 - How can I select vector layer from drop down menu

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

On my map, I have an OpenStreetMap tiles in the background and a VectorLayer on top. Now I want VectorLayer to be changed by user via drop down menu. How can I achieve this?

Here's my HTML drop down menu code:

```
<select id="line">
    <option value="1a">Line 1A</option>
    <option value="1b">Line 1B</option>
    <option value="2a">Line 2A</option>
    <option value="2b">Line 2B</option>
</select>
```

Here's my map script:

```
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
            url: 'tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            crossOrigin: null,
            })
          }), linelayergroup
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([100.568, 14.353]),
          zoom: 14,
          minZoom: 14,
          maxZoom: 19,
          extent: [11187608.82, 1608083.02, 11203003.55, 1621297.19],
          constrainResolution: true
        })
      });
```

And here's my VectorLayer 1a script:

```
    var layer1a = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source1a,
        style: function(feature) {
            allbusstyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
            return allbusstyle;
        }
    });
```

How the code of `var linelayergroup` should be?, to be the VectorLayerGroup that can be changed by `value` in the HTML drop down menu. For example, if user select `Line 1A` in drop down menu, the VectorLayer will change from default to layer `layer1a`, and if user select another choice, the VectorLayer will change from `layer1a` to that choice.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways.

1- Toggling visibility: You can add all 4 layers to the map. When user select a layer in the dropdown menu you should turn that layer `visible` and make others `hidden`.
This can be done easily by an event handler on the dropdown menu(you should on `change` toggle visibility of layers).

```
var object = document.getElementById("line");
object.addEventListener("change", function(){
    layer1a.setVisible(false);
    // same for other layers

    switch(object.value){
        case "1a":
            layer1a.setVisible(true);
            break;
        // same for other layers
    }
});
```

2- Changing source: Also you can change the layer source. in this way, you should add only one layer. when user selects from list you need to replace layer source and re-render it. so the layer will be changed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! I've got it. I've used your code and it works fine. Thank you.